# Soll man vor/nach dem Wort „bitte“ ein Komma setzen?

Tags: spelling, comma

Wann ist es notwendig, nach der Höflichkeitsformel „bitte“ ein Komma zu setzen? Muss ich zum Beispiel in den Sätzen:

> Bitte(,) bring mir wieder das ausgeliehene Buch zurück!

oder

> Mach das jetzt endlich(,) bitte!

ein Komma verwenden? Gibt es vielleicht eine *je-nachdem*-Regel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Duden [erklärt wie folgt](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Kommasetzung-bei-bitte), dass beides korrekt ist, auch wenn es sich um unterschiedliche Konstrukte handelt:

> Das kleine Wörtchen bitte kann in fast allen Situationen einen Beitrag zur höflichen Gestaltung einer Aufforderung oder eines Wunsches leisten. Es wird häufig formelhaft gebraucht und kann am Anfang eines Satzes, in der Mitte oder auch am Ende auftauchen: „Bitte schick mir doch die Fotos von unserem letzten Urlaub zurück." Oder: „Leg doch bitte auch die Negative dazu." Oder in kurzen Sätzen: „Antworte bitte." Oder auch einfach nur: „Bitte!"
>
> Entstanden ist es aus „ich bitte [darum]", weshalb es auch als Auslassungssatz aufgefasst und nachdrücklich betont werden kann: „Bitte, schick mir doch endlich die Fotos zurück." Oder: „Leg doch, bitte, auch die Negative dazu." Oder: „Kümmere dich darum, bitte!" In diesen Fällen wird „bitte" – den Kommaregeln entsprechend – durch Komma[s] abgetrennt.
> In Verbindung mit einem Infinitiv ist es ungewöhnlich, bitte als Verbform zu behandeln. Deshalb wird der Infinitiv in der Regel ohne zu gebraucht: „Bitte nicht stören!" „Bitte leserlich schreiben!" Selten zu finden sind Abweichungen wie „Bitte die Rückseite zu beachten!".

Comment: +1: Also includes the answer of [my question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/bitte-in-the-sentence).

Answer (score 2):

Meines Wissens ist beides korrekt.

http://www.werbewolf.ch/News-Inhalte/Sammel%20Duden/10komma.html

Da 'bitte' als Kurzform von 'ich bitte darum' (oder ähnlich) aufgefasst werden kann, ist der Gebrauch eines Kommas nicht falsch. Das Komma ist jedoch nicht notwendig.

Answer (score 1):

Ich finde die Antwort "beides korrekt" für einem konkreten Anwendungsfall nicht sehr hilfreich. Besser wäre m. E. eine Faustregel. Ich würde eine solche so formulieren:

- Fast immer schreibt man "bitte" *ohne* Komma (nämlich dann, wenn man, "häufig formelhaft, einen Beitrag zur höflichen Gestaltung einer Aufforderung oder eines Wunsches leisten" möchte).

  So deckt es sich zumindest mit meiner Praxiserfahrung: In meinem letzten Jahr E-Mail-Korrespondenz habe ich "bitte" *immer* ohne Komma geschrieben.
- Nur, wenn man die Bitte *nachdrücklich betonen möchte* (was oft heißt, dass man die Bitte bereits zum zweiten oder dritten Mal formuliert), schreibt man "bitte" *mit* Komma (vor oder nach dem "bitte").

Wenn man viel mit Menschen zu tun hat, die man regelmäßig mehrfach bitten muss, ändert sich diese Faustregel natürlich ...